# Show that multiplication is not definable on set of Natural Numbers with successor function

Tags: logic

I've shown that the theoty in the question admits quantifier elimination.
If the $F(x,y)=xy$ (multiplication) was definable on $\mathbb{N}$ with successor function and $0$ then the statement $A=\text{"There is }x \text{ s.t for any }y \; F(x,y)=x$" is true.
Now, I want to show that $A$ is not equivalent to formula $A'$ without quantifiers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any sentence (i.e., formula with no free variables) is either  true or false, so every sentence is equivalent either to $0 = 0$ or to $0 \neq 0$.